# EXTJS Grid dataIndex customisation and my misunderstanding

Tags: extjs

I want to put some custom data in to column field... my data located at the local store.

```
code of my grid:


columns: [
{text: "name", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'name'},
{text: "type", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'type'},
{text: "value", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'function', renderer: this.rendeValueColumn},
{text: "parameter", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'parameter'},
{text: "rule", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'rule'}
],

i want to change 'rule' .

i'm try to : var a = 'test'; {text: "rule", flex: 1, dataIndex: a} etc...

but that way arent help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

dataIndex do not expect data. It expect name of data field.

What you really want is

```
columns: [
  {text: "name", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'name'},
  {text: "type", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'type'},
  {text: "value", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'function', renderer: this.rendeValueColumn},
  {text: "parameter", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'parameter'},
  {text: "rule", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'name', renderer: function(){
    return 'test';
  }}
],
```

You can use renderer function to put in any data you want.